# Find the tangent plane given the following level curve and point on a surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Surface is $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 2$, $x_0 = (1,1,0)$

I calculate the gradient vector, which also serves as the normal vector at $x_0$. 
\begin{align}
\nabla f(1,1,0) = (2x, 2y, -2z) = (2,2,0)
\end{align}

Then

\begin{align}
0 &= \nabla f(x_0) \cdot (x-x_0) \\
0 &= (2,2,0) \cdot (x-2, y-2, z-0) \\
&= 2(x-2) + 2(y-1) + 0 \\
&= 2x - 4 + 2y - 2 \\
6 &= 2x + 2y
\end{align}

However, my textbook says that the tangent plane is really $x + y = 2$. Did I set something up wrong? Here is the reasoning my textbook gives for taking the dot product of $\nabla f(x_0)\cdot (x-x_0)$. Maybe I am not understanding how to use the equation properly?

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}, n \geq 2$ be continuously differentiable at $x_0$ and let $S$ be a level set of $f$ containing $x_0$. If $\nabla f(x_0) \neq 0$, then $\nabla f(x_0)$ is a normal vector to $S$ at $x_0$, and all points $x$ in a tangent line or plane to $S$ at $x_0$ satisfy the equation $$\nabla f(x_0) \cdot (x-x_0) = 0$$

Comment: It is $2 (x-2) +2 (y-2)+0$

Comment: That would still only give me $2x + 2y = 8$ or $x + y = 4$

Comment: @Still_a_kid It is not. You’re making the same mistake that the OP did in using the value of the gradient instead of the coordinates of $x_0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve mistakenly used the components of $\nabla f(x_0)$ instead of the coordinates of $x_0$ itself when computing the equation of the plane. You should have $$\nabla f(\mathbf x_0)\cdot(\mathbf x-\mathbf x_0) = (2,2,0)\cdot(x-1,y-1,z-0) = 2(x-1)+2(y-1) = 2x+2y-4=0.$$

Comment: ah thank you, can't believe I got that mixed up!

Comment: @EvanKim It happens to the best of us.